# measure Pingtime to host from java application

Tags: java, icmp

Im looking for a way to measure ping delay time to a list of servers. It is important that it is only the actual packet delay that is measured as exactly as possible and not jvm computation time.

Some aspects has been covered in the answers here: [How to do a true Java ping from Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448666/how-to-do-a-true-java-ping-from-windows)

Measuring the time of InetAddress.isReachable(timeout) I think is not an option as it didnt work towards some of the servers I need to ping.

The closest I got so far is using processbuilder as shown in the answers in above link.

I've also found jpcap library: http://netresearch.ics.uci.edu/kfujii/Jpcap/doc/download.html but going native comes with a cost.