# Java Local IP range detect

Tags: java, ip, range, lan

I am working on a LAN based software, for which I require to detect the range in which systems in the network lies, using Java. The function is required to be similar to "Detect local IP range" in Netscan, a Windows utility software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are wanting the actual local subnet IP range, rather than a list of alive IP addresses in the local subnet, you can use the following code to get the subnet mask size:

```
InetAddress localHost = Inet4Address.getLocalHost();
NetworkInterface ni = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(localHost);
InterfaceAddress ia = ni.getInterfaceAddresses().get(0);
short mask = ia.getNetworkPrefixLength();
```

That will give you a `short` primitive with a value of 1-32, probably 24. Then you can use

```
byte[] b = ia.getAddress().getAddress();
```

Which will give you a `byte[]` which you will mask against the subnet `mask` to give you the local address range in some usable format.

---

Alternatively if you want a list of alive hosts on the local subnet, an arp-scan using [JPCap](http://netresearch.ics.uci.edu/kfujii/Jpcap/doc/) is the method I would use.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using "ping".

This post has some code on ping to start.

[How to do a true Java ping from Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448666/how-to-do-a-true-java-ping-from-windows)