# why the isReachable() method always return "false"?

Tags: java, ping

I want to get the delay time between 2 PC by this way:

```
currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();           
isPinged = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.6.18").isReachable(2000);                 
currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - currentTime;
System.out.println("----"+isPinged+":"+currentTime);
```

but the results always be "false" except "localhost",I tried change the `getByName("192.168.6.18")` to the PC of LAN ,or the website like "www.facebook.com",but it has no effect

Comment: Have you used something like `ping` to ensure that you actually *can* reach the host in question?

Comment: please refer to this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922543/why-does-inetaddress-isreachable-return-false-when-i-can-ping-the-ip-address

Comment: yes I have used `ping` in CMD and it worked

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem with isReachable in InetAddress class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779367/problem-with-isreachable-in-inetaddress-class)

Answer (score -3):

Use this method for Windows PC

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public Boolean ping(String ipaddress)
{
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    String cmds = "ping "+ipaddress;
    System.out.println(cmds);
    Process proc;
    try {
         proc = runtime.exec(cmds);
        proc.getOutputStream().close();
        InputStream inputstream = proc.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader inputstreamreader = new InputStreamReader(inputstream);
        BufferedReader bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(inputstreamreader);
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedreader.readLine()) != null) {
            if(line.contains("Reply from "+ipaddress+":"))
                {
                return true;    
                }
            }
        }catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
 }
```

for more details see [Ping class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12059932/pinging-computer-by-name-in-java/22898040#22898040)

For PC other than windows use

```
  public Boolean IsReachable(String ipaddress) {
    try {            
        final InetAddress host = InetAddress.getByName(ipaddress);

        try {
            return host.isReachable(3000);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: And what if his OS has no `ping` command? And what if the result from the `ping` does not contain English text? This is not scalable solution.

Comment: This is not a good general solution. (1) The `ping` command may not exist. (2) The `ping` output may not be in that format - OS X will say `x bytes from`, and on non-English versions of Windows the messages will be translated into the local language.

Comment: Falling back to the same method that the OP says isn't working is not helpful.

Comment: Also, beware that some implementations of `ping` do not terminate (until you send a signal such as SIGINT). Heavy use of this could fill your process table and end up generating a *lot* of traffic.

Comment: I agree with your knowledge but it does not make sense to vote down my answer... it contains a solution.

Comment: It is a very low quality solution, for all the reasons I have listed. Down-voting is appropriate for low quality answers.