# Open port 7 for echo in java

Tags: java, sockets, port, ping, connection-refused

I am trying to do simple ping operation using java code , i know that java does not support icmp so i just made a simple code that uses port 7 to send a request and wait for echo response

```
 Socket t = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 7);
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(t.getInputStream());
    PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(t.getOutputStream());
    ps.println("Hello");
    String str = dis.readUTF();
    if (str.equals("Hello"))
      System.out.println("Alive!");
    else
      System.out.println("Dead");
    t.close();
```

but this gives me

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
at MobileCloud.Ping.main(Ping.java:11)
```

I read that i should change in the /etc/inetd.conf file but I have no such file .

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Ports < 1024 require root to open or admin on Windows.

Comment: You need to start the service that listens on port seven first.

Comment: Not your question exactly, but see - [How to do a true Java ping from Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2448666/127035)

Comment: @aioobe ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 1):

> Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

There is no server running on port 7 as you might verify with `telnet 127.0.0.1 7`. Thus the connection gets refused.

> I read that i should change in the /etc/inetd.conf file but I have no such file

This depends on the system. You might need to install inetd. With your Ubuntu 14.04 this will be the `inetutils-inetd` package.

Comment: ICMP uses port 7 so it should echo my message when i send a string with "hello" it should respond back.  I just need to listen on port 7

Comment: ICMP does not use any ports at all. Ports are for TCP and UDP only.

Comment: I just need to study the RTT for some measurments so do you have alternative solution ?

Comment: I think this is better asked as a new question, which should contain enough details about the environment  where you need to measure the RTT and the restrictions you have.